# How can I spawn an object at my player?

Tags: java

I got a player and bullets. The bullets spawn at a fixed spot. How can I make them spawn in front of my player? How do I get my player X and Y into my code below? I cannot figure it out.
This is the KeyInput class. SPACE To Shoot. When I shoot I want the bullet to spawn at my Player:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import Game.Game.STATE;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter{

    private Handler handler;
    private boolean[] keyDown = new boolean[4];

    Game game;

    public KeyInput(Handler handler, Game game){
        this.handler = handler;

        this.game = game;

        keyDown[0] = false;
        keyDown[1] = false;
        keyDown[2] = false;
        keyDown[3] = false;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            // Player Movement
            if(tempObject.getid() == ID.Player){
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) { tempObject.setVelY(-5); keyDown[0] = true; }
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) { tempObject.setVelY(5); keyDown[1] = true; }
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) { tempObject.setVelX(-5); keyDown[2] = true; }
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) { tempObject.setVelX(5); keyDown[3] = true; }

                //Player Shoot
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
                    handler.addObject(new PlayerBullet(400, 400, ID.PlayerBullet, handler));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            // Player Movement Release
            if(tempObject.getid() == ID.Player){
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) keyDown[0]=false; //tempObject.setVelY(0);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) keyDown[1]=false; //tempObject.setVelY(0);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) keyDown[2]=false; //tempObject.setVelX(0);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) keyDown[3]=false; //tempObject.setVelX(0);

                // Y Movement
                if(!keyDown[0] && !keyDown[1]) tempObject.setVelY(0);
                // X Movement
                if(!keyDown[2] && !keyDown[3]) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            }
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P){
            if(Game.gameState == STATE.Game){
                if(Game.paused) Game.paused = false;
                else Game.paused = true;
            }
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Player class:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;

public class Player extends GameObject {

    public static float PlayerHealth = 100;

    Random r = new Random();
    Handler handler;

    public Player(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler){
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 32, 32);
    }

    public void tick(){
        timer--;

        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        PlayerHealth = (int)Game.clamp(PlayerHealth, 0, 100);
        x = Game.clamp((int)x, 0, Game.WIDTH - 38);
        y = Game.clamp((int)y, 0, Game.HEIGHT - 61);

        handler.addObject(new Trail((int)x, (int)y, ID.Trail, Color.GREEN, 32, 32, 0.1f, handler));
        handler.addObject(new PlayerBullet((int)x+16, (int)y-12, ID.PlayerBullet, handler));

        collision();
    }

    private void collision(){
        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){

            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if (tempObject.getid() == ID.BasicEnemy || tempObject.getid() == ID.PlayerBullet){
                if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                    // Collision code
                    HUD.PlayerHealth -= 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){

        // Show borders
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.draw(getBounds());

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 32, 32);
    }
}
```

My Player movement keys are in the KeyInput so yes I Think it has access. I just need to figure out how to change the current 400, 400 to my player X and Y instead.

Comment: Something like `int x = player.getX()`. Depends how it works in your code... so how does that work in your code? Do you have a place that stores the current player position?

Comment: I have nothing that stores my player position X and Y. Can't figure out how to get that in either. Player code below;

Comment: Text is 900 characters too long. I cannot give you the code...

Comment: You can use the [edit] button and improve your question.

Comment: Mark it with the mouse and hit the `{}` button. That's what I usually do. (It's the same as CTRL+K, I guess you didn't have the code snippet selected)

Comment: Finally I got it. Also needed so much more info Before I could post it, don't mind the random //INFOS

Comment: The `Player` object (or actually any `GameObject`) has an `x` and a `y` property that stores the position. The way that `PlayerBullet`s are generated is roughly what you need to do. Do you have any way to access the `Player` object in the code that needs the location? `Game.getPlayer()` or so? If not maybe you need to add a way.

Comment: I obviosuly have no idea what I am doing in Java so I posted the Player and KeyInput class. The problem lies within those I "think"

Comment: `tempObject` is the player object. It has the right ID. So `tempObject.x` or probably `tempObject.getX()` (if that method exists), is the way you can access the player's location.

Comment: tempObject.X
tempObject.x
tempObject.getX
All those tempObject."whatever" has now been tested and nothing works.

Comment: Look into the `GameObject` class. Is there a `getX()` or similar method that does `return x;`? There should be some sort of method that returns the `x` variable. Also the `()` in  `.getX()` is important

Comment: I got it to work with the X one but Y is stuck at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

```
handler.addObject(new PlayerBullet((int)tempObject.getX()+10, (int)tempObject.getY()-12, ID.PlayerBullet, handler));
```

I forgot the () in tempObject.getY

I am stupid:
Solved...